# Getting each values from a value list python

Tags: python, angularjs, django, list, django-rest-framework

Hi I have a custom Django/python resource/view. as follows

```
class ResourceView(JSONResponseMixin, View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    status = 'error'
    msg = "Success"
    # Getting the x value from url/queryset
    x= self.request.GET.get('x')
    mas = self.request.GET.get('mas')

    queryset_df = Forecast.objects.filter(Q(x=int(fab)) | Q(x=int("0"+x)))\
        .values_list('mas').distinct()

    queryset_or = Record.objects.filter(Q(pc_ext__x=int(x)) | Q(pc_ext__x=int("0"+x)))\
        .values_list('mas').distinct()

    new_mas_list = list(set(list(queryset_df) + list(queryset_or)))
    new_mas_list.sort()
    return self.render_json_response(dict(objects=new_mas_list))
```

Which returns a value list of masksets. How to get each value of the valuelist(Because in my html, i have a dropdown to display each valuelist objects, displays fine; but when I select one it returned me as a value list object as `["5300A"]` instead of 5300A. I am using AngularJS to get the value as follows:

```
//UPDATE MAS BASED ON USER FAB
$scope.update_mas = function(){
    $scope.processing['update_mas'] = { msg: 'loading mas..', class: 'text-warning', show: true };
    console.log('Stage1: Loading Mas..... ');
    $http.get('{% url "masresourceview"  %}', { params: { x: $scope.x} }).success(
        function(data){
            $scope.processing['update_mas'] = { msg: 'mas updated.', class: 'text-success' };
            setTimeout(function () { $scope.processing['update_mas'] = null; $scope.$apply(); }, 1000);
            $scope.maslist = data['objects'];
            $scope.isDisable = true;
            console.log($scope.maslist);

        }).error(function(data, status){
            $scope.processing['update_mas'] = { msg: 'Internal Error', class: 'text-danger' };
            console.log('Stage1: Internal error while loading initial data:'+status );
        });
};
```

My resource/list looks like this:

```
{
objects: [
[
"AMD14NM"
],
[
"BAFFIN1"
],
[
"BAGERA1"
],
[
"ELLSMR1"
],
[
"GARFLD1"
],
[
"GARFLD2"
],
```

When I put `$scope.maslist = data['objects'][0];` I can get the first object's value perfectly. What I can do for the rest of the object's values? Do I need to improve my views.py/resources? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use `$scope.maslist = data['objects'](your array) after that in html smth like that. http://jsfiddle.net/nnpngxc1/

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/jkog5ph0/1/ But i prefer prepare array before display it. Ramda.flatten for example. http://ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten

Comment: Sorry, what is R before flatten?

Comment: ramda.js it's alias for Ramda. ;)

Comment: But you can use anything you want, lodash, underscore and others.

Comment: Worked Thanks a lot Errorpro :)

Comment: You can point my asnwer as correct to help other people find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the return part with `flatten`.

`from compiler.ast import flatten`

`return self.render_json_response(dict(objects=flatten(new_mas_list)))`

Answer (score 0):

Here  is an example: jsfiddle.net/jkog5ph0/1 But i prefer prepare array before display it. Ramda.flatten for example. ramdajs.com/docs/#flatten

Answer (score 0):

Though previous answers look correct, you have a simpler way to handle this on the server side.

`values_list`has a `flat` argument to return a flat list instead of list of lists (https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Therefore your view should be:

class ResourceView(JSONResponseMixin, View):

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    status = 'error'
    msg = "Success"
    # Getting the x value from url/queryset
    fab = self.request.GET.get('x')
    mas = self.request.GET.get('mas')

    # DRCForecast Masksets
    queryset_df = Forecast.objects.filter(Q(x=int(fab)) | Q(x=int("0"+x)))\
        .values_list('mas', flat=True).distinct()
    # OrcRecord Masksets
    queryset_or = Record.objects.filter(Q(pc_ext__x=int(x)) | Q(pc_ext__x=int("0"+x)))\
        .values_list('mas', flat=True).distinct()

    new_mas_list = list(set(list(queryset_df) + list(queryset_or)))
    new_mas_list.sort()
    return self.render_json_response(dict(objects=new_mas_list))
```